# how to ->paginate() on a inner join Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-paginate

Trying to paginate a inner join but it does not work.

This it my code

```
    $positions = DB::table('position')
    ->join('company', 'position.company_id', '=', 'company.id')
    ->select('position.*', 'company.name')
    ->paginate(15)
    ->get();
```

This is what the array looks like (without the paginate->())

```
Array(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [company_id] => 1
        [title] => Software Developer
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [company_id] => 2
        [title] => Accountant
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [company_id] => 3
        [title] => Insurance salesman
    )
```

and this is what i use

```
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paginate is different than get method either get for all or paginate for paginated get not both.

remove the get and it will work. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination